# Query database where month is equal to

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a query where I need to select entries only where their month is equal to a certain month.

Each entry has the date saved in the ymd format (20140211).

I have tried the following, but it doesn't recognise the month.

```
AND (MONTH(matrix.col_id_3) = '1' OR MONTH(matrix.col_id_4) = '1')
```

Is this due to the date format? I am stuck with this format as its part of the CMS I use.

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use the default date column type (why?) so you have to convert your column

i.e.

```
... MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(matrix.col_id_3,'%Y%m%d')) = 1 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

probably your dates are stored as strings, so you could use the following

```
.... SUBSTRING(matrix.col_id_3, 5, 2) = '01' ...
```